# Django pre_save signal has to be saved twice from admin to take affect

Tags: python, django, django-models

Got Django 1.11 app.  Everything is working fine, except a strange issue with a pre_save signal.  In my model, I have two many to many fields that I'm using to calculate total cost in model in question (bandwidth and license).

I created a pre_save signal to accomplish this, and it works, but from the admin I am having to click the "Save" options twice for the Sku cost to update correctly.

Code snippet below.  Thanks for looking.

Note: I tried just doing this as a save override and the results are the same, so not sure if it is just an issue with Django admin or something I'm doing.

```
class Sku(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    bandwidth = models.ManyToManyField(Bandwidth, blank=True, null=True)
    license = models.ManyToManyField(License, blank=True, null=True)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, null=True, blank=True, related_name='sku')
    cost = models.DecimalField(max_digits=25, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)

    def list_bandwidth(self):
        return ', '.join([ b.vendor for b in self.bandwidth.all()[:3]])

    def list_license(self):
        return ', '.join([ b.name for b in self.license.all()[:3]])

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


def sku_receiver_function(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if instance.id:
        bandwidth_cost = 0
        license_cost = 0

        if instance.bandwidth:
            for b in instance.bandwidth.all():
                bandwidth_cost = float(b.cost) + bandwidth_cost

        if instance.license:
            for l in instance.license.all():
                license_cost = float(l.cost) + license_cost

        instance.cost = bandwidth_cost + license_cost

pre_save.connect(sku_receiver_function, sender=Sku)
```

Comment: Have you check the django shell after you do a single save in admin, and if the value is updated correctly (when using the shell)?

Comment: I did, yes. Put a print in and after logic and when clicking save would print the old value.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the error is in the first line in pre_save signal because the first time when run this code the instance doesn't have id, then don't execute the rest of the code, because the condition is false, but at the end, this asign the id to instance and save, then in the second save the instance have id and the condition is true. **You can change pre_save by post_save and the code will work fine.**

Sorry for my English.

Comment: I did this with the if instance.id logic removed and got same results, but will try this with post save and get back. Thanks!